# Let $f$ entire funtion such that $\left|f(z)\right|=1$ when $|z|=1$. Then $f(z)=Cz^{m}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $C\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|C|=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ entire function such that $\left|f(z)\right|=1$ when $|z|=1$. Show that $f(z)=Cz^{m}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $C\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|C|=1$.

**My attempt**:  Since $f$ is entire we have that power series at $0$ 
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$$
is convergent in all $\mathbb{C}$. I show that $|c_{n}|\leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This is about the Schwarz reflection principle. Did you already see something like $g(z) = \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$.

Let  $g(z) = \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{c_n} z^{-n}$. It is analytic on $|z| > 0$.

Note that for $|z| = 1$ : $g(z) = \overline{f(z)}$, and since $|f(z)| = 1$ we have $g(z) f(z) = 1$.

By the identity theorem this means $fg = 1$.

Let $m$ be the order of vanishing of $f(z)$ at $z=0$. Then $g(z) = O(z^{-m})$. Therefore $\frac{f(z)}{z^m}$ is a bounded entire function, so by Liouville's theorem it is constant.

Qed $f(z) = A z^m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $|A|=1$.

Comment: The "Therefore" is not so clear.  But $f$ has no zeros except at $0$, where it must have one unless $f$ is constant (by Liouville).  If the zero at $0$ has order $m$, then apply Liouville to $f(z)/z^m$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I thought we could expand $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n)(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{c_n} z^{-n})$ and conclude, but you are right, it is not so easy and Liouville's theorem is better. So this exercice is more a (difficult) exam question ?

Comment: In complex analysis courses, the first example of a non-holomorphic function is $ h(z) = \overline{z}$, you are using $ h $ to define $ g $. Why is $ g $ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{0\right\}$? This for me is not obvious, you are composing functions that are not holomorphic.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca That's why I wrote it $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \overline{c_n} z^{-n}$ to make obvious it is analytic on $|z| > 0$